# Scroll function not working properly - Flet Python

Tags: python, flet

I have a column with a Text widget and programmatically added buttons.
When I add the buttons, I also give them an on-click event where the container scrolls to the according text container.

However, every button goes to the 'D' row instead

```
cl = ft.Column(
        spacing=10,
        height=180,
        width=300,
        scroll=ft.ScrollMode.ALWAYS
    )

    for index in range(4):
        character = chr(index + ord('A'))
        container = ft.Container(
                ft.Text("Section " + character),
                alignment=ft.alignment.top_left,
                bgcolor=ft.colors.BLUE_200,
                height=100,
                key=character
            )
        cl.controls.append(container)

    buttons = ft.Column([ft.Text("Scroll to:")])

    buttonRow = ft.Row()
    for index in range(4):
        character = chr(index + ord('A'))
        button = ft.ElevatedButton(
            "Section " + character,
            on_click=lambda _: cl.scroll_to(key=character, duration=1000)
        )
        buttonRow.controls.append(button)

    buttons.controls.append(buttonRow)

    page.add(ft.Container(cl, border=ft.border.all(1)), buttons)
```